# callable in ThreadPoolExecutor is not blocking

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I'm using ThreadPoolExecutor to execute a blocking call which is send a shell command to a remote shell for execution.

When I run it without threading, the command call will block the execution on the main thread. However, as I run it as the following code in an executor. The call doesn't block anymore, the times printed are the same. What did I do wrong here?

```
  exe = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)


  def _run():
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    client.Shell('cmd --time-limit=35')
    print(datetime.datetime.now())

  f = exe.submit(_run)
  time.sleep(30)
  client.Shell('killall cmd')
```

Comment: we use threads to create non-blocking code so I don't understand what you expected. maybe you should use `f.result()` to wait for end of thread.

Comment: I was expecting client.Shell('cmd --time-limit=35') will block in the thread since it blocks when running without threading, and client.Shell('killall cmd') shall unblock it?

Comment: maybe for some reason `Shell(...)` gets error and doesn't block it. Some modules are not "thread safe" and they have problem to run in separated thread. You should check module which you use to create `client` if it can works in thread.